# How to fetch the latest email from thread in AWS Workmail

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-workmail

Im trying to get only the latest response from incoming emails in AWS Workmail but my code currently fetches the whole email thread. I have an inbound rule that sends the incoming emails to a Lambda

```
client = boto3.client('workmailmessageflow')
response = client.get_raw_message_content(messageId=message_id)
    
message_bytes = response['messageContent'].read()
message_content = message_from_bytes(message_bytes)
    
message = ""
    
# Iterate through the MIME message parts
for part in message_content.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
        try:
            message = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode('utf-8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            continue
        break  # Only get the first "text/plain" content; ignore the rest to avoid fetching the whole thread
```

How do I get only the latest response? I imagined this to be a simple task as the email client already knows what response is the newest but I guess not :( I could try regex but its likely to fail as emails are formatted differently depending on email provider